# What's the life span of a PostgreSQL server-side prepared statement

Tags: database, postgresql, session, jdbc, prepared-statement

According to the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html), a prepared statement is bound to a database session/connection:

> PREPARE creates a prepared statement. A prepared statement is a
>   server-side object that can be used to optimize performance. When the
>   PREPARE statement is executed, the specified statement is parsed,
>   analyzed, and rewritten. When an EXECUTE command is subsequently
>   issued, the prepared statement is planned and executed.
>
> Prepared statements only last for the duration of the current database
>   session. When the session ends, the prepared statement is forgotten,
>   so it must be recreated before being used again.

But then, [Markus Winand (author of SQL Performance Explained) says that](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/explain-plan/postgres/concrete-planning):

> PostgreSQL does not have a shared query plan cache, but it has an
>   optional query plan cache for prepared statements. That means that the
>   developer has the choice to use a prepared statement with or without
>   cached query plan. But note that the cache is dropped when the
>   prepared statement is closed.

Which one is true?

Does the prepared statement live as long as the database connection is open, so when using a connection pool this can live as long as the pool doesn't explicitly closes the physical connection or does the server-side prepared statement is wiped out once the JDBC *PreparedStatement* is closed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

So, your question finally boils down to "how `java.sql.PreparedStatement` plays with PostgreSQL". See answer on "how this plays with server-prepared plans" in the end.

Here's the answer: that depends on the JDBC driver you use.

**TL;DR**: in modern drivers server-prepared statement lives until connection dies or until the statement is evicted by another one (regular LRU eviction).

Note: PostgreSQL server cannot share prepared statement across database connections, thus the best JDBC driver can do is to keep plan cached in each connection.

Note: JDBC spec mandates usage of `?, ?` for bind placeholders, while server wants `$1, $2` thus JDBC drivers cache so-called parsed SQL texts as well.

There are two well-known JDBC drivers: pgjdbc and pgjdbc-ng

## pgjdbc

https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc

Since [pgjdbc 9.4-1202](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html#version_9.4-1202) it automatically caches server-side plans when using `PreparedStatement`.
Note: the statements are cached even if you `close()` the `PreparedStatement`.
In order to get to server-side prepare, you need to execute the query 5 times (that can be configured via `prepareThreshold`).

Currently, the cache is implemented per-connection. By default pgjdbc caches 256 (`preparedStatementCacheQueries`) queries and up to `preparedStatementCacheSizeMiB` of queries. This is a conservative setting, so you might want adjusting it. See [documentation](https://github.com/pgjdbc/www/blob/master/documentation/94/connect.md) for the description of properties.
The cache includes both parsed and server-prepared statements.

github issue: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/319

## pgjdbc-ng

https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng

I'm not into pgjdbc-ng, however it looks like it does both parsing (default cache size is [250](https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng/pull/69/files#diff-1bebf577851eb82e19f61761968b2729R44) queries) and server-preparing (default cache size is [50](https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng/pull/69/files#diff-1bebf577851eb82e19f61761968b2729R47) queries). The support of server-side prepared statements landed on 24 Feb 2014, so if you use somewhat recent version, you can get statement caching.

Note: if you accidentally use very long queries, you can hit `OutOfMemory` since pgjdbc-ng cannot evict entries based on the number of retained bytes.

The cache is per-connection, thus it is transparently used even if you close statements.

I cannot say much about pgjdbc-ng performance though since last time I tried to throw jmh at it it failed with random exceptions.

github issue: https://github.com/impossibl/pgjdbc-ng/pull/69

## Server-prepared plans

PostgreSQL has `PREPARE` and `DEALLOCATE` commands to reference the statement when sending `EXEC` over the wire. It optimizes two things:

1. When using `PREPARE`d statement (in other words, server-prepared one), client does not have to send query text again and again. It just sends a short query name and the values for bind variables.
2. Since 9.2, database still tries to replan first few executions of a query. It does so to try if the query needs multiple plans or if generic plan is good enough. Eventually (immediately if the query has no parameters), the database [might switch to a generic plan](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-prepare.html#AEN82140).
3. Since 12, there's a setting to force ALL server-prepared statements to be executed with generic or custom plans: [plan_cache_mode](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING)=`auto | force_custom_plan | force_generic_plan`

In other words, `PreparedStatement` optimizes both query parsing at JDBC side and query planning at database side.

More info here: http://blog.endpoint.com/2014/04/custom-plans-prepared-statements-in.html

## Prepared statements in PL/pgSQL

As per documentation, PostgreSQL [caches](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-PLAN-CACHING) plans for queries used in PL/pgSQL. This happens after a few executions (3 or 5, I do not remember the exact threshold), so after you create stored procedure it might be a bit slow, however then it will switch to cached plans (provided the database agrees to use generic plan for a particular query).

In other words in order to achieve "cached execution plans", you either need to use up to date JDBC driver, or you can wrap all your queries into stored procedures.
The call to procedure will replan at each execute, however the call itself is typically much shorter than queries that compose the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see you've been working on this feature on 9.4. So, it means the prepared statement is available for the current connection even after the PreparedStatement gets closed. This is great news, since it allows reusing the parsing/compiling for frequently executed statements.

Comment: One more note: Since 9.2, PostgreSQL doesn't create the execution plan with the PREPARE call--the actual planning is done only at EXECUTE time (clearly stated in the quote from the docs given by @VladMihalcea. That means: all of the caching is only about caching the re-written query — not the execution plan.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's the parsing, rewrite and compiling that gets cached. The associated execution plan is deferred to execution time.

Comment: @MarkusWinand, you are a bit off again. Eventually PostgreSQL will cache the execution plan, so using prepared statements does improve execution.

Answer (score 3):

I think both are true, but in doubt the PostgreSQL documentation usually more true than me. However, here I think the PostgreSQL doc might be inaccurate.

It should probably read like this:

> Prepared statements only last until it is [DEALLOCATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-deallocate.html)ed and no longer than the duration of the current database session.

Without checking I would strongly believe that the JDBC driver deallocates the server-side prepared statement when the JDBC PreparedStatement is closed.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to add this question on the PG mailing list too.

Comment: Both `pgdjbc` and `pgjdbc-ng` cache statements across `close()` calls since lots of applications are written in `prepare-execute-close` way.