# JDBC batch operations understanding

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

I use Hibernate ORM and PostgreSQL in my application, and sometimes i use batch operations. 
And at first I didn't understand why in the logs with size of the batch =  25, 25 queries are generated, and at first thought that it does not work correctly.
But after that I looked at the source code of the pg driver and found the following lines in the PgStatement class:

```
 public int[] executeBatch() throws SQLException {
        this.checkClosed();
        this.closeForNextExecution();
        if (this.batchStatements != null && !this.batchStatements.isEmpty()) {
            this.transformQueriesAndParameters();
//confuses next line, because we have array of identical queries
            Query[] queries = (Query[])this.batchStatements.toArray(new Query[0]);
            ParameterList[] parameterLists = 
(ParameterList[])this.batchParameters.toArray(new ParameterList[0]); 
            this.batchStatements.clear();
            this.batchParameters.clear();
```

and in PgPreparedStatement class

```
    public void addBatch() throws SQLException {
        checkClosed();
        if (batchStatements == null) {
          batchStatements = new ArrayList<Query>();
          batchParameters = new ArrayList<ParameterList>();
        }

        batchParameters.add(preparedParameters.copy());
        Query query = preparedQuery.query;
    //confuses next line
        if (!(query instanceof BatchedQuery) || batchStatements.isEmpty()) {
          batchStatements.add(query);
        }
      }
```

I noticed that it turns out that if the size of the batch goes 25, 
25 queries are sent with the parameters attached to them.

Logs of the database confirm this, for example:

```
2017-12-06 01:22:08.023 MSK [18402] postgres@buzzfactory СООБЩЕНИЕ:  выполнение S_3: BEGIN
2017-12-06 01:22:08.024 MSK [18402] postgres@buzzfactory СООБЩЕНИЕ:  выполнение S_4: select nextval ('tests_id_seq')
2017-12-06 01:22:08.041 MSK [18402] postgres@buzzfactory СООБЩЕНИЕ:  выполнение S_2: insert into tests (name, id) values ($1, $2)     
2017-12-06 01:22:08.041 MSK [18402] postgres@buzzfactory ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  параметры: $1 = 'test', $2 = '1'
2017-12-06 01:22:08.041 MSK [18402] postgres@buzzfactory СООБЩЕНИЕ:  выполнение S_2: insert into tests (name, id) values ($1, $2)
2017-12-06 01:22:08.041 MSK [18402] postgres@buzzfactory ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  параметры: $1 = 'test', $2 = '2'
...
x23 queries with parameters 
...
2017-12-06 01:22:08.063 MSK [18402] postgres@buzzfactory СООБЩЕНИЕ:  выполнение S_5: COMMIT
```

But i thought one query must be executed with an array of 25 parameters.
Or I don't understand how batch inserts work with a prepared statement? 
Why duplicate one query n times?

After all, i tried to debug my queries on this place

```
if (!(query instanceof BatchedQuery) || batchStatements.isEmpty()) {
```

and noticed that my queries are always instance of SimpleQuery instead of BatchedQuery. Maybe this is the solution to the problem? Information about BatchedQuery i couldn't find

Comment: This might be a question that you'd better ask on the postgresql-jdbc mailinglist.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There might be various kinds of batching involved, and I would cover PostgreSQL JDBC driver (pgjdbc) part of it.

TL;DR: pgjdbc does use less network roundrips in case batch API is used. `BatchedQuery` is used only if `reWriteBatchedInserts=true` is passed to the pgjdbc connection settings.

You might find https://www.slideshare.net/VladimirSitnikv/postgresql-and-jdbc-striving-for-high-performance relevant (slide 44,...)

When it comes to query execution, network latency is often a significant part of the elapsed time.

Suppose the case is to insert 10 rows.

1. No batching (e.g. just `PreparedStatement#execute` in a loop). The driver would perform the following

   ```
   execute query
   sync <-- wait for the response from the DB
   execute query
   sync <-- wait for the response from the DB
   execute query
   sync <-- wait for the response from the DB
   ...
   ```

   Notable time would be spent in the "waiting for the DB"
2. JDBC batch API. That is `PreparedStatement#addBatch()` enables driver to send multiple "query executions" in a single network roundtrip. Current implementation, however would still split large batches into smaller ones to avoid TCP deadlock.

   The actions would be much better:

   ```
   execute query
   ...
   execute query
   execute query
   execute query
   sync <-- wait for the response from the DB
   ```
3. Note, that even with `#addBatch`, there's overhead of "execute query" commands. It does take server notable time to process each message individually.

   One of the ways to reduce the number of queries is to use multi-values insert. For instance:

   ```
   insert into tab(a,b,c) values (?,?,?), (?,?,?), ..., (?,?,?)
   ```

   This PostgreSQL enables to insert multiple rows at once. The drawback is you don't have detailed (per-row) error message. Currently Hibernate does not implement multi-values insert.

   However pgjdbc can rewrite regular batch inserts into multi-values on the fly since 9.4.1209 (2016-07-15).

   In order to activate multi-values rewrite, you need to add `reWriteBatchedInserts=true` connection property. The feature was initially developed in https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/491

   It is smart enough to use 2 statements in order to insert 10 rows. The first one is 8-valued statement, and the second one is 2-valued statement. Usage of powers of two enables pgjdbc to keep the number of distinct statements sane, and that improves performance as often-used statements are server-prepared (see [What's the life span of a PostgreSQL server-side prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32297503/whats-the-life-span-of-a-postgresql-server-side-prepared-statement/32300222#32300222) )

   `BatchedQuery` is representing that kind of multi-valued statements, so you will see that class used in `reWriteBatchedInserts=true` case only.

   The drawbacks of the feature might include: lower details as the "batch result". For instance, regular batch gives you "per statement rowcount", however in multi-values case you just get "statement completed" status. On top of that, on-the-fly rewritter might fail to parse certain SQL statements (e.g. https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1045 ).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested my application with this flag, the performance increased many times with batch inserts.
But not everything is as good as it turned out. I saw that in the latest versions of the pg driver, the constructions **do nothing**, and **do update set column=value** was fixed.But constructions **on conflict do update set column =?** does not work. It is understandable, it is unlikely that this can lead to a single SQL query. Therefore I had to disable this flag.

Comment: @Birthright, feel free to create an issue for the case that does not work (see https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues )

Comment: @Birthright, this might resolve your case: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/1130

Comment: Thanks, I got a x5 speed increase by turning on the reWriteBatchedInserts=true

Answer (score 1):

Batch processing does not collapse or minimize the number of SQL statements done; it is all about optimizing how Hibernate caches and flushes things to the database in its in-memory session.  The importance of batch processing and finding the right batch size for your operation is to find the right balance between app memory used and database performance.

- You will run out of app server memory if you do too many queries before committing/flushing a batch
- you will not get the best performance if your batch size is too small and you are committing/flushing too often.

More reading here.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_batch_processing.htm